# Using two string functions within an array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to use both **str_replace** and **ucfirst** functions on the data in the array I am building.

Current code: `opening_times[ str_replace( $venue_slug . '_', '', $day) ] = $time;`

I tried comma separating it but that did not work.

```
$opening_times[ str_replace( $venue_slug . '_', '', $day), ucfirst( $day ) ] = $time;
```

When working, my current output is the following. I just need to capitalise the first letter. **But not by using CSS.**

```
monday 12:00 - 00:00
```

Full code:

```
$days = [
    $venue_slug . '_monday',
    $venue_slug . '_tuesday',
    $venue_slug . '_wednesday',
    $venue_slug . '_thursday',
    $venue_slug . '_friday',
    $venue_slug . '_saturday',
    $venue_slug . '_sunday',
    ];

$opening_times = array();

foreach ( $days as $day ) {

    $opening_time = get_acf_option( $day . '_open' );
    $closing_time = get_acf_option( $day . '_close' );

    if ( $opening_time && $closing_time ) {
        if ( $opening_time !== '' && $closing_time !== '' ) {

            $time = $opening_time . ' - ' . $closing_time;

        } else {
            $time = 'Closed';
        }
    }

    $opening_times[ str_replace( $venue_slug . '_', '', $day), ucfirst( $day ) ] = $time;
}
```

Comment: ucfirst( str_replace( $venue_slug . '_', '', $day) )

Comment: @tan perfect, thank you. I can accept this as an answer if you want to put it as one.

Comment: To those giving down votes, explain why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform second operation on the result of the first one.

change this

```
str_replace( $venue_slug . '_', '', $day), ucfirst( $day )
```

to

```
ucfirst( str_replace( $venue_slug . '_', '', $day) )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try applying uppercase on first letter for the whole output that is

```
ucfirst(*your code*);
```

Hope this helps